# Beginners project: calculating area

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

This was my second project as a beginner in Java programming. Please provide feedback/ tips on my program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Area {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner Area = new Scanner (System.in); 

        double length, width,totalArea, height; 
        String shape, unit;
        int loop = 0; 

        while (loop == 0){ 

        System.out.println("Which shape do you want to find the area?");
        shape = Area. next(); 

        switch (shape) { 

        case "rectangle": 
            System.out.println("Please enter the leghth of the rectangle: ");
            length = Area. nextDouble (); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();  
            totalArea = length*width; 
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        case "square" : 
            System.out.println("Please enter the leghth of the square: ");
            length = Area. nextDouble (); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the width of the square: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();
            totalArea = length*width; 
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        case "triangle" : 
            System.out.println("Please enter the base of the triangle: ");
            length = Area. nextDouble (); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the height of the triangle: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();
            totalArea = ((length*width)/2); 
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break;

        case "parallelogram" : 
            System.out.println("Please enter the base of the parallelogram: ");
            length = Area. nextDouble (); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the height of the parallelogram: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();  
            totalArea = length*width; 
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        case "circle" : 
            System.out.println("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
            length = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();  
            totalArea = 3.14*(Math.pow(length, 2));
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        case "rhombus" : 
            System.out.println("Please enter the first diagonal of the rhombus: "); 
            length = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the second diagonal of the rhombus: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();  
            totalArea = ((length*width)/2);
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        case "trapezoid" :
            System.out.println("Please enter the first base of the trapezoid: "); 
            length = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the second base of the trapezoid: ");
            width = Area. nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the height of the trapezoid: ");
            height = Area.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
            unit = Area.next();  
            totalArea = (((length+width)*height)/2);
            System.out.println(totalArea+unit);
            break; 

        default: 
            System.out.println("The shape you entered is not recongnized");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about classes and polymorphism?

Answer (score 6):

First, you have improved yourself. But I still see the habit of your

```
 int loop = 0; 

        while (loop == 0){...
```

structure in [both the programs you have written so far](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/135729/64992) *(Your program doesn't actually iterate as you don't change the `loop` variable)*. Actually, while loops are faster than any other loops. On the other hand, it is also important to write more clean & clear code.

As your loop-body is not more than 5000 or more lines, it's better to use a `do-while(){...}` looping structure.

---

### Polymorphism (Factory Pattern + Strategy Pattern)

You can use Polymorphism in your program to make it nice. *(If you don't know [what is polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1031273/4506140))*

*Switch cases are good* but **replacing switch-case with polymorphism is fantastic**. Look, you have different things to do in each switch case. Basically, different shapes formed with different ways.

**Shape Interface**

```
public interface Shape {

    double calculateArea();
    void buildShape(Scanner scanner);
}
```

**ShapeClub.java (Main class)**

```
public class ShapeClub {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean retry = false;

        do{
            System.out.println("Which shape do you want to find the area?");
            Shape unknownShape = ShapeFactory.getShape(scanner.next());
            unknownShape.buildShape(scanner);

            System.out.print("Do you want to try a different shape?[Y/N]:");
            retry = scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
        }while (retry);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**ShapeFactory.java (Factory class)**

```
public class ShapeFactory {

    private ShapeFactory(){}

    public static Shape getShape(String shapeName){
        switch (shapeName){
            case "rectangle":
                return new Rectangle();
            case "circle":
                return new Circle();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Rectangle.java (Concrete class)**

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {

    private double length = 0.0;
    private double width = 0.0;
    private String unit ="";

    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        return length*width;
    }

    @Override
    public void buildShape(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the leghth of the rectangle: ");
        length = scanner.nextDouble ();
        System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
        width = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
        unit = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(calculateArea()+unit);
    }
}
```

**Circle.java (Another concrete class)**

```
public class Circle implements Shape {

    private double radius = 0.0;
    private String unit ="";

    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        return Math.PI*(Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public void buildShape(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
        radius = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the unit of the shape?");
        unit = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(calculateArea()+unit);
    }
}
```

*Hope you understood it. :)*

Comment: Your shape factory probably wants to return an unknown shape as a default, or you need to check the response in ShapeClub, at the moment you can end up calling buildShape on a null object

Comment: The statement that "while loops are faster than any other loops" is not true. The byte code generated by a traditional for loop and a while loop is the same. If you're talking about a for-each loop then there is a difference, but generally it's so negligible that it's not worth trying to optimize. Furthermore the difference between a while and do-while loop is also negligible - the byte code differs by a single command. It's highly unlikely that the type of loop will be a performance bottleneck anyway, so there is little point in bringing up this level of detail especially to a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed at first a copy-paste problem between square and rectangle shapes. To illustrate, using your program:

> ```
> Which shape do you want to find the area?
>  square
> Please enter the leghth of the square: 
>  4
> Please enter the width of the square: 
>  3
> What is the unit of the shape?
>  cm
> 12.0cm
> ```

Your program is asking for both the "leghth" (length) and width of the square, which should both be the same. The code for a square and a rectangle is identical, which is wrong.

This should work nicely:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the length of each side of the square: ");
length = Area.nextDouble ();
totalArea = length*length;
```

---

I found a bug:

> ```
> Which shape do you want to find the area?
>  circle
> Please enter the radius of the circle: 
>  foo
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:68)
> ```

If you are expecting only numbers as input, you should provide a way to handle this exception. Here is an example way to handle it with a do-while loop:

```
        case "circle" : 
            boolean isValidNumber = false;
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
                try {
                    length = Area.nextDouble();
                    isValidNumber = true;
                } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number input.");
                }
            } while(isValidNumber = false);
```

---

#### `while (loop == 0)`

This condition is never negated, and in your case it means the program never ends, unless forcibly done by quitting the execution, or by an exception. You should provide a mechanism for the user to quit the program.

---

The `main` method is intended to be the entry point of the program only, and not the entire program. As [Crazy Ninja suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135818/42632) you program would be made a lot cleaner by extracting the shapes into their own classes and such.

---

You should declare your variables individually for improved clarity.

> ```
>     double length, width,totalArea, height; 
>     String shape, unit;
> ```

Should be:

```
    double length;
    double width;
    double totalArea;
    double height; 
    String shape;
    String unit;
```